# Is there any way of opening a new tab in chrome without using ctrl + t through selenium webdriver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am working with selenium webdriver and JAVA. I would like to open a new tab in chrome browser without using CTRL + T, As it requires the browser to remain in focus. Is there any way where browser is not in focus and we can still manage to open a new tab?

Comment: Why would the browser NOT be in focus while running automation?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

I would think that would bring the browser back into focus. Or click on some random element that results in no action and then `sendKeys()`.